# Am I making some mistake with Chutzpah.json file?

Tags: angularjs, json, jasmine, resharper, chutzpah

I am trying to test Angular using jasmine:

My Folder structure: 
[image]

My chutzpah.json file:

```
{
"Framework": "jasmine",
 "TestHarnessLocationMode": "Custom",
 "TestHarnessDirectory": "../AngularExample",
"TestHarnessLocationMode": "SettingsFileAdjacent",
"TestHarnessReferenceMode": "AMD",

"References": [ 
     {"Path": "../AngularExample/Controller","Include": "app.js"} ],

"Tests": [
    { "Path": "/Tests/Specs" }
 ],
"AMDBasePath": "../AngularExample/Controller"
}
```

I am getting below error message:
[image]

My code files are referred from here(reffering example from https://gist.github.com/blesh/8846528

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you are referencing Angular.js library itself. Please take a look at the [Angular samples with Chutzpah](https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/tree/master/Samples/Angular) and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks! I dropped the idea of using chutzpah.json. I tried to use /// <reference path="jasmine/filename.js" /> and it works for me. How ever I want to refer all files in one folder <reference path="../../AngularExample/Scripts" />  it fails. I have to reference each file seperately as of now. Is there a way I can refer to all files in that directory.

Comment: I would need to see a full sample. But did you look at the samples part of chutzpah? Do those help? 

I highly recommend using chutzpah.json file.